# AngularJS: Nested Directives - passing data not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive inside another directive while the first directive gets an array and for each item in the array call the other directive.

i'm having trouble with passing the data correctly.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5yKGb0hawwr4btHCrkIJ?p=preview)

Here is my code:

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "first"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "second"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "third" 
    }]
  }
})

.directive('firstDirective', function() {
  return {

    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A', 
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      
      var template = ''; 
      angular.forEach(attrs.data, function(item, key) {
          var tmp = '<div>' +
                          // '<h4>First Directive</h4>' +  
                          '{{dataFirst}}' +
                          '<div second-directive data="' + item + '"></div>' +
                    '</div>';
          element.append(tmp);          
      });
    }

  }
})

.directive('secondDirective', function() {
  return {
 
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var template = '<div class="second-directive">' +
        '<h4>Directive 2</h4>' +
        'ID :' + attrs.data + '<br />' +
        'Name : ' + attrs.data +
        '</div>';

      element.replaceWith(template);
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.second-directive{
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:4px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head> 

 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>MainCtrl</h2>
    {{data}}

    <div first-directive data="data.items">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot

Avi

Comment: have you tried scope.data in angular.forEach ?

Comment: "compile" executes before the scope. therefore it has no access to it.

Comment: ohh ya that's compile phase.

Comment: found the error actually you are using angular.forEach on a string because attr.data will give you a string not an object .

Comment: Then how do i get the object?

Comment: you will have do that in link phase it's not possible to get object from attrs.

Comment: After looking your code,why you need two directives?What you want achieve?

Comment: This is just an example i need 2 for loading dynamic template for different objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's everyone.

This is the solution i cam up with.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "first"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "second"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "third"
    }]
  }
})

.directive('firstDirective', function($compile) {
  return {

    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var template = '';
      angular.forEach(scope.data, function(item, key) {
        var sss = JSON.stringify(item).replace(/"/g, "'"); 
        var tmp = '<div>' +
          '<div second-directive data="' + sss + '"></div>' +
          '</div>';
          
          template = template + tmp;

      });
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
})

.directive('secondDirective', function() {
   var comp = function(element, attrs){
      var data = JSON.parse(attrs.data.replace(/'/g, "\""));
      var template = '<div class="second-directive">' +
        '<h4>Directive 2</h4>' +
        'ID :' + data.id + '<br />' +
        'Name : ' + data.name +
        '</div>';

      element.replaceWith(template);
    
  }
 
  return {

    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: comp
  };
});
```

```css
.second-directive{
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:4px;
  text-align:center;
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head> 

 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>MainCtrl</h2>
    {{data}}

    <div first-directive data="data.items">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you want to call other directive for each item in the array.

you can do it in this way .

HTML :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div first-directive>
        <div ng-repeat="oneEle in  data.items">
          <div second-directive dirval="oneEle">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

directive('secondDirective', function() {

```
  var tmp = '<div>' +
              '<div class="second-directive" >'+
              '<h4>Directive 2</h4>' +
              'ID :  {{dirval.id}} <br />' +
              'Name : {{dirval.name}}</div>' +
              '</div>';

  return {

    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      dirval: '='
    },  
    template : tmp


  }
})
```

if you want load dynamic template for different object, you can pass in **$scope.data** object.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHddV2Hw3pwQdWVzVpU5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks but i need to display the first directive multiple times in the page and i don't want to ng-repeat many times.
That's why i didn't do it your way (ng-repeat).